# Cannot go beyond login screen

Tags: macos, login, login-screen

I was performing a routine restart this evening, and all went as per normal until I logged in with my password to my user account. The computer encountered a kernel panic towards the end of the decryption progress bar and insisted on restarting. So far, despite what I have tried, I have not been able to get beyond the login.

FileVault 2 was recently enabled on my computer.

I have tried the following, to no avail:

- NVRAM reset
- SMC reset
- Apple Diagnostics (returned all OK)
- Disk Utility First Aid

I am yet to try the following:

- fsck_hfs
- complete wipe and reinstall

My data has been backed up as this is the beta system.

Specs:
Mid-2014 i7 MacBook Pro 11,1
MacOS Sierra Public Beta 4

Comment: Why are you still running an old beta!? IMO There is no good reason to still be running an old beta. I'd wipe the drive and do a clean install of macOS 10.12.1 from a USB Installer.

Comment: @user3439894 I was going to upgrade soon, but my life got cluttered and due to circumstances upgrading wasn't possible. I'll wipe the drive and see if that works. Thanks!